# RichTextBox Paste limited to 32k chars?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a WinForms application with a RichTextBox.
If I copy 100k chars from Notepad++ text and try to use <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> on RichTextBox, only 32.200 chars are pasted in.
Note that I can go on typing in RichTextBox, so problem is not `MaxLength`.
Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: Does right-clicking on the `RichTextBox` and Selecting Paste work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No repro, I just pasted 1.4 million characters from Notepad into an RTB.  You'll need to consider another source of the problem, pebkac or Notepad++.  Check if the syntax coloring is preserved when you paste into the RTB.  In which case the limitation is on the amount of RTF that Scintilla is willing to generate.  Which is a fair one, programmer Q+A sites don't allow that much text in a post.

Comment: Regarding pebkac, how can you possibly fail at copying text? :p

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN - RichTextBox.MaxLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.maxlength.aspx)

```
RichTextbox1.Length = Int32.MaxValue;
```

This should give you 2,147,483,647 characters

Comment: @Marco can you use CTRL+V to paste the full text in some other text processor such as NotePad or Word without issues?